# javascript error requiring double inclusion of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I was making a website and moved around the scripts a bit in the page and all of a sudden some of the scrips stopped running on my clients PC. I had to do some hit and try and it finally worked, but I cant figure out what caused the problem.

this is the structure when it wasnt working

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='somepath/script/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//some custom jquery script
</script>
</head>
<body>
....lots of stuff
</body>
</html>
<script type='text/javascript' src="sompath/some_jquery_plugin.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//some custom jquery script
</script>
```

this is the structure when it was working

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='somepath/script/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//some custom jquery script
</script>
</head>
<body>
....lots of stuff
</body>
</html>
<script type='text/javascript' src='somepath/script/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="sompath/some_jquery_plugin.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
//some custom jquery script
</script>
```

i.e notice the additional jquery.js inclusion at the end....

what possible reasons could have caused this? specially since it was working on my system on all browsers but not my clients.

******update*****************
I think jquery stopped working somewhere in the middle... i.e I had this script at the end

```
$('#start').val('0000.00.00 00:00');
$('#end').val('0000.00.00 00:00');
```

but the fields with "start" and "end" id werent showing the given data. hence the extra inclusion of jquery required.

Comment: Are both your plugin and script using the document ready handler: $(document).ready(function(){your script}); or shorthand: $(function(){your script});? Locally the content and scripts load almost instantly, but on clients there is latency and transfer time.

Comment: I dont think you need the upper one js on client machine. Use both scripts wither on top or at bottom. Once i read some where that may be the libraries at the bottom load first or last. And you must not use two jquery ever as some functions execute twice..

Comment: @TheGwa and @KSaini : the `<script>` tags load from top to bottom and the inline scripts won't be run before the scripts that are above have already been downloaded and executed. The `$(document).ready(function(){})` is used to make sure that the DOM is ready (including the elements below the script) and not to make sure that the jQuery is loaded (if it wasn't then you wouldn't even have the `$` or `jQuery` to run `$(document).ready(function(){})`)

Comment: @death_relic0 it would be easier to solve your problem if you cared to comment whether at least some of the several advices that I included in my answer worked or not.

Comment: Sorry, I realise I may seem rude, thing is it was working on my system from the start but not on my clients. I am working on setting up a page with just the relevent code and share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the first inline script use [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) (or `$.noConflict`)? Does the "`....lots of stuff`" in your example load some other library like Prototype that might redefine the `$` object? This may be the problem.

Try putting all of your code in the second script tags inside of:

```
(function ($) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
}(jQuery));
```

(and remove the second jQuery inclusion) and see if that helps.

If your code is already wrapped in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // your code
});
```

or:

```
$(function () {
    // your code
});
```

then try changing it to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // your code
});
```

or:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // your code
});
```

(**note that it's `function ($)` instead of `function ()`**)

(You may also need to put the plugin just below the first jQuery in case it is not written in a way that works with `$` undefined or redefined but generally that shouldn't be necessary for plugins written properly.)

Comment: regarding your last part of putting the jquery inclusion right before the plugin,  Is it possible that this error would occur in some systems not others? cause this could be it...

Comment: @death_relic0 it all depends on what the code in both inline scripts is doing and how the plugin is written. Did you try removing the second jquery.js inclusion and wrapping your code in `(function ($) {` **...** `}(jQuery));` as I showed in my answer?